# IPython IDE for Windows

Tags: python, debugging, ide, ipython

I recently installed IPython after hearing about it on this forum.  I am looking for an environment that is similar to what might come with MATLAB or RStudio for R.

I was under the impression that IPython would give me that but the version I downloaded for Windows looks very bare.  In fact I do not really see a difference between IDLE and IPython except tab completion and history (which I have been wanting) but this is about as much as the interpreter that comes with R which I used to think was hard to work with.

Have I misunderstood the point of IPython? Or is it possible that I have not installed correctly?

I have also downloaded the 'Console' and while I am not convinced that it is working properly, it looks very bare as well.

Komodo looks good but is somewhat costly.  Netbeans and Eclipse also look good, but do not seem to be straightforward to install, at least for somebody with my level of knowledge, so it would be good if somebody could verify their compatibility with Python, features, and ease of use for a non-expert user.

Comment: If you want a complete set up, look at Python distributions like Python(x,y), Anaconda or EPD - they give you one download bundling all the bits you need.

Answer (score 6):

I suggest you try Spyder
You can find it here : https://www.spyder-ide.org/

It is perfect for you : it is a lightweight Scientific IDE with the explicit purpose of being similar in feel to matlab.
It has an editor, a console and lots of neat features and plug-ins.
It can use IPython as its console.

IPython is "just" an enhanced python console with pure awesomeness built-in. (actually it's much more : it's a client-server architecture with multiple interfaces to pure magic, in console mode, Qt, and even inside a browser with the Notebook)
Definitely check it out later on when you've used the basic console for a while.

Comment: I second spyder.  you can also get spyder as part of python xy, http://code.google.com/p/pythonxy/

Comment: Another distribution for Windows that includes Spyder is WinPython. WinPython has versions for both Python 2.7 and 3.3. http://winpython.sourceforge.net/

Answer (score 3):

For the context, i've been using Eclipse, pycharm, got tired of those, and i started to ask around what people use, and the one i've heard the most about is [sublime text](http://www.sublimetext.com/).
You should take a look, maybe it's what you are looking for! 
I just saw it's not open source though!

What i'm using now is [Ninja-IDE](http://ninja-ide.org/), which is written in python and is open source and seems pretty good! It has plenty of plugins, which includes an IPython plugin

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried the [`qtconsole`](https://ipython.org/ipython-doc/3/interactive/qtconsole.html) backend?  It was released after you asked your question.

> This is a very lightweight widget that largely feels like a terminal,
>   but provides a number of enhancements only possible in a GUI, such as
>   inline figures, proper multiline editing with syntax highlighting,
>   graphical calltips, and much more.

From the Windows command prompt, enter:

```
ipython qtconsole
```

[image]